# Material UI / React - close accordion onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a form within an accordion - what I want to do is when the form is submitted collapse the accordion.

```
<Accordion elevation={3}>
<AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
</AccordionSummary>
<AccordionDetails>
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
</form>
</AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>

const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("meals")
      .add({
        Name : name,
      })
      //.then will reset the form to nothing
      .then(() => setName("");
  };
```

Ideally in the .then of the firebase add I would collapse the accordion from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the expanded prop of the Accordion when submiting the form.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true);


<Accordion expanded={expanded} > </Accordion>
```

When submiting the form , you have to set the prop to false

```
const submit = () => {

// ...
setExpanded(false);
}
```

Acording to your need , this is example which make you do the job :

[code example on sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledaccordions-material-demo-forked-r57bk)

So the point here is to call the same function **handleChange** with a string(panel name) different to the ones given to each accordion.

Hope this help you.

Comment: OK it works, but if doing this I can no longer manually toggle the accordion open/closed.

Comment: im going to change my answer , so you can expand/collapse your accordions and collapse them all when submiting the form in that way

Answer (score 0):

Crete an “expanded” Boolean state variable and bind it to the expanded props of the accordion https://mui.com/api/accordion/

Then, set this state variable to false in your “then” callback.