# How can I manually set accordion close on button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am completely new to React. Here is the code I currently have. I removed some unnecessary parts to keep it clean.

```
<AccordionSummary
  expandIcon={}
  aria-controls="panel1a-content"
>This is Accordian
<AccordionSummary/>  
<AccordionDetails>
  <Grid container spacing={4} mb={5}>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <FormControl>
        <RadioGroup
          aria-labelledby="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group"
          name="controlled-radio-buttons-group"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            value="yes"
            name="Yes"
            control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
            label="Yes"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value="no"
            name="No"
            control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
            label="No"
          />
      
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Button className={classes.button_dark} variant="contained">
      Submit
    </Button>
    <Button className={classes.button_light}>Cancel</Button>
  </Grid>
</AccordionDetails>
```

I was using controlled accordion where I want a change, but I tried various combinations referring MUI docx, but I'm not getting any soln. This is the states I have used, but this one is for a radio button.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const {value} = e.target;
  setValue(value);
};
```

What I want is that whenever I click the cancel button, the accordion should hide. The expand icon is working, but here I want to hide the accordion whenever I press the cancel button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material UI / React - close accordion onSubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109371/material-ui-react-close-accordion-onsubmit)

Answer (score 0):

In MUI `Accordion` there's a property called `expanded` which accepts a boolean value and using that you can manually control the expansion and hide the according. You need to maintain a state to do that. Here's a basic example.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState();

<Accordion expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={() => setExpanded('panel1')}>
   // items inside the accordion
   <Button className={classes.button_light} onClick={() => setExpanded(undefined)}>Cancel</Button>
</Accordion>
```

This is just a simple solution to your problem.
[refer to this for more details](https://v4.mui.com/components/accordion/#controlled-accordion)

**Update**
Here's a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-hooks-3ki6r9)

Comment: Here I cannot use expanded command which not in button Api..

Comment: And why you have given here undefined?

Comment: what do you mean you can't use expanded? it's just a prop in `MUI Accordion', And passed undefined to make sure the state has no value when you click the cancel button.

Comment: updated the question with `codesandbox` example, please refer to that, you'll get the idea